# Creating dump file at the moment of access violation

Tags: c++, .net, c, debugging

I would like to create process dump file at the moment when access violation that will not be handled occurred.

Currently, I have registered mine, unhandled exception callback with:

```
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(CustomUnhandledExceptionFilter);
```

CustomUnhandledExceptionFilter creates dump file and prints call stack.

But this approach has one flaw - it is done when AV has already happened, AV exception is thrown and has not been handled by thread it happened in. Unhandled exception callback is called when exception is about to leave thread scope and dump created at this point has no local variables of function that exception occurred since stack pointer is lost.

Is there an way to over come this? I would like to take a look at stack of thread that got AV at the moment AV happened.

Comment: This can only go wrong if you don't pass the EXCEPTION_POINTERS you got from the filter to MiniDumpWriteDump().  Post a snippet if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VS

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>

LONG WINAPI MyUnhandledExceptionFilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
                L"proc.dmp",
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                CREATE_ALWAYS,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL
            );
    MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION mei;
    mei.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    mei.ClientPointers = TRUE;
    mei.ExceptionPointers = ExceptionInfo;
    MiniDumpWriteDump(
        GetCurrentProcess(), 
        GetCurrentProcessId(), 
        hFile, 
        MiniDumpNormal,
        &mei,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyUnhandledExceptionFilter);
    int* p = NULL;
    *p = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

WinDbg

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test\Debug\proc.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7600 UP Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sat Dec 15 19:29:31.000 2012 (UTC + 4:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: not available
......................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(8d8.1084): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=fffffffd ebx=005d0d78 ecx=0022f070 edx=778964f4 esi=005d0d38 edi=0022f110
eip=778964f4 esp=0022edd0 ebp=0022ede0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
778964f4 c3              ret
0:000> .ecxr
eax=00000000 ebx=7ffdf000 ecx=0022fa30 edx=778964f4 esi=0022fcf4 edi=0022fdcc
eip=0124157c esp=0022fcf4 ebp=0022fdcc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for dump.exe
dump!wmain+0x3c:
0124157c c70001000000    mov     dword ptr [eax],1    ds:0023:00000000=????????
0:000> dv
           argc = 0n1
           argv = 0x00280e38
           p = 0x00000000
0:000> kb
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0022fdcc 01241b19 00000001 00280e38 0027f9c8 dump!wmain+0x3c [d:\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test\dump\dump.cpp @ 35]
0022fe1c 01241d0d 0022fe30 76051194 7ffdf000 dump!__tmainCRTStartup+0x199 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c @ 533]
0022fe24 76051194 7ffdf000 0022fe70 778ab495 dump!wmainCRTStartup+0xd [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c @ 377]
0022fe30 778ab495 7ffdf000 7676831a 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0022fe70 778ab468 0124107d 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0022fe88 00000000 0124107d 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000> u .
dump!wmain+0x3c [d:\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test\dump\dump.cpp @ 35]:
0124157c c70001000000    mov     dword ptr [eax],1
01241582 33c0            xor     eax,eax
01241584 5f              pop     edi
01241585 5e              pop     esi
01241586 5b              pop     ebx
01241587 81c4cc000000    add     esp,0CCh
0124158d 3bec            cmp     ebp,esp
0124158f e8c0fbffff      call    dump!ILT+335(__RTC_CheckEsp) (01241154)
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

GetPageUrlData failed, server returned HTTP status 404
URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/dump_exe/0_0_0_0/50cc9743/dump_exe/0_0_0_0/50cc9743/c0000005/0001157c.htm?Retriage=1

FAULTING_IP: 
dump!wmain+3c [d:\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test\dump\dump.cpp @ 35]
0124157c c70001000000    mov     dword ptr [eax],1

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0124157c (dump!wmain+0x0000003c)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
Attempt to write to address 00000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_WRITE

PROCESS_NAME:  dump.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000000 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
dump!wmain+3c [d:\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test\dump\dump.cpp @ 35]
0124157c c70001000000    mov     dword ptr [eax],1

MOD_LIST: <ANALYSIS/>

FAULTING_THREAD:  00001084

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_POINTER_WRITE

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_POINTER_WRITE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 01241b19 to 0124157c

STACK_TEXT:  
0022fdcc 01241b19 00000001 00280e38 0027f9c8 dump!wmain+0x3c [d:\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\test\dump\dump.cpp @ 35]
0022fe1c 01241d0d 0022fe30 76051194 7ffdf000 dump!__tmainCRTStartup+0x199 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c @ 533]
0022fe24 76051194 7ffdf000 0022fe70 778ab495 dump!wmainCRTStartup+0xd [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c @ 377]
0022fe30 778ab495 7ffdf000 7676831a 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0022fe70 778ab468 0124107d 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0022fe88 00000000 0124107d 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAULTING_SOURCE_CODE:  
    31: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    32: {
    33:     SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyUnhandledExceptionFilter);
    34:     int* p = NULL;
>   35:     *p = 1;
    36:     return 0;
    37: }
    38: 


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  dump!wmain+3c

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: dump

IMAGE_NAME:  dump.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  50cc9743

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_POINTER_WRITE_c0000005_dump.exe!wmain

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_POINTER_WRITE_dump!wmain+3c

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/dump_exe/0_0_0_0/50cc9743/dump_exe/0_0_0_0/50cc9743/c0000005/0001157c.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Great, thanks!

The code I have is similar to yours, except ClientPointers is set to FALSE. I am not sure how this influences debugging. I did not know how to use provided context (.ecxr), which you showed as well.

The code and windbg output you provided is a great example on registering custom unhandled exception handler, creating dump and later analyzing it.

Comment: When I use `L"proc.dmp"` instead of `"proc.dmp"`, the file that gets generated is just called `p` instead of `proc.dmp`. Just a heads up for anyone else seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using AddVectoredExceptionHandler. The thread context of the moment of exception is passed as an argument to the callback proc of this method.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am not sure what is the difference with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(), since UnhandledExceptionFilter function is also provided with EXCEPTION_POINTERS*. Am i missing something?

Comment: Yep, you're right. When I was answering question I didn't remember the exact parameters of a SEH handler. What was in my mind is that I succesfully used VEH for writing minidumps in my own project. So I suggest to use them, thinking that this information is unavailable in SEH handlers. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the exception context intact you can create the minidump from an outer process, which debugs the process of interest with `DebugActiveProcess` API and receives exception events as a part of debugging. Minidump creation preceding release of the debugee with `ContinueDebugEvent` preserves call stack and exception context.

Comment: But I don't see how can I create dump from an outer process on unhandled exception.

Comment: You receive "exception event" and before you call `ContinueDebugEvent` in the outer process (debugger) the debugee is on hold. It is perfect time to make a dump and the stack you need is right there.

Comment: This method requires external process and privileges, but is superior to unhandled exception filter because it captures all exceptions, and in finest detail. Not just those reaching filter and with possibly damaged context.

Comment: Major drawback of this approach - you can't simply attach with a normal debugger as only one debugger is allowed.