# Dump call stack on error?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm debugging a program written in plain C (no C++, MFC, .NET, etc.) to the WIN32API.  It must compile in both VS2005 (to run under Win 2K/XP) and VS2010 (to run under Win7.)  I've been unable to duplicate a bug that my customer seems able to duplicate fairly reliably, so I'm looking for ways to have my program "debug itself" as-it-were.  It is monitoring all of the key values that are changing, but what I'd really like to see is a stack dump when a value changes.  Oh, I cannot run a "true" debug build (using the debug libraries) without installing the compiler on the customer's machine and that is not an option, so this must be built into my release build.

Is there any way to do this other than just adding my own function entry/exit calls to my own stack monitor?  I'd especially like to be able to set a hardware breakpoint when a specific memory address changes unexpectedly (so I'd need to be able to disable/enable it around the few EXPECTED change locations.)  Is this possible?  In a Windows program?

I'd prefer something that doesn't require changing several thousand lines of code, if possible.  And yes, I'm very underprivileged when it comes to development tools -- I consider myself lucky to have a pro version of the Visual Studio IDEs.

--edit--
In addition to the excellent answers provided below, I've found some info about using hardware breakpoints in your own code at http://www.codereversing.com/blog/?p=76.  I think it was written with the idea of hacking other programs, but it looks like it might work find for my needs, allowing me to create a mini dump when an unexpected location writes to a variable.  That would be cool and really useful, especially if I can generalize it.  Thanks for the answers, now I'm off to see what I can create using all this new information!

Comment: Offtopic: If you can't reproduce it and the customer can, then it's most likely some configuration on their side.

Comment: @m0skit0 this is a baseless assumption

Comment: @m0skit0 The customer's machine has hardware that I cannot since it is part of a system monitoring the preprocessing of uranium into fuel for power plants.  They won't let me have that stuff in my office, and I find myself unable to simulate it well enough to duplicate the bug.

Comment: Creating dump file at the moment of access violation http://stackoverflow.com/q/13876222/1888362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MiniDumpWriteDump` function which creates a dump, which can be used for post-mortem debugging. In the case application crashes, you can call `MiniDumpWriteDump` from unhandled exception handler set by `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. If the bug you are talking about is not crash, you can call `MiniDumpWriteDump` from any place of the program, when some unexpected situation is detected. More about crash dumps and post-mortem debugging here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu

The main idea in this technique is that mini dump files produced on a client site are sent to developer, they can be debugged - threads, stack and variables information is available (with obvious restrictions caused by code optimizations).

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is almost exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of Win32 functions in dbghelp32.dll that can be used to produce a stack trace for a given thread: for an example of this see [this code](https://github.com/DavidKinder/Windows-Inform7/blob/master/Inform7/StackTrace.cpp).

You can also look up the StackWalk64() and related functions on MSDN.

To get useful information out, you should turn on PDB file generation in the compiler for your release build: if you set up your installer so that on the customer's computer the PDB files are in the same place as the DLL, then you can get an intelligible stack trace out with function names, etc. Without that, you'll just get DLL names and hex addresses for functions.

I'm not sure how practical it would be to set up hardware breakpoints: you could write some sort of debugger that uses the Win32 debugging API, but that's probably more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer as well as the MiniDump suggestion.  Since I think the MiniDump will be a bit easier to use (not requiring extra files installed on the customer machine) I'll go with it, but I'll remember the StackWalker64 because it seems useful, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can add **limited** instrumentation to raise an identifiable exception when the symptom recurs, you can use [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4060) to generate a full process dump on any instance of that exception.

I find I cite this tool very frequently, it's a real godsend for hard-to-debug production problems but seems little-known.

Comment: Wow, three valid and useful answers!  If the MiniDump doesn't provide enough info, I think that ProcessDumper will be the next thing I try.  Thanks!